Spring Boot Data Elasticsearch querying documents' collection with multiple fields
In Elasticsearch, I have an index with the following mapping (simplified):
{
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
    },
    "eventId": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "null_value": "NULL"
    },
    "statuses": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "null_value": "NULL"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "null_value": "NULL"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Let's assume that we have the following data in the index:



eventId
statuses.message
statuses.status




ID1
M1, M2
INFO, ERROR


ID2
M2, M4
OK, INFO


ID3
M5
INFO



I would like to make a query using the Criteria API that will search by eventId, statuses.message, and statuses.status fields. But for the last two fields, the appropriate documents should be returned only in the case when the query finds a document with both required values in the same object in the collection.
So, for the query
eventId: ID1 and [M1] in statuses.message and statuses.status: INFO

there should be a match. But for the query:
eventId: ID1 and [M2] in statuses.message and statuses.status: INFO

should not return any value, because there isn't an object in statuses that have message: M2 and status: INFO.
I've created the following query but it doesn't work quite as intended:
var criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.and(new Criteria(EVENT_ID.getLabel()).is(request.getEventId()));

Criteria subCriteria = new Criteria()
    .and(STATUSES_MESSAGE.getLabel()).in(request.getMessageCodes())
    .and(STATUSES_STATUS.getLabel()).is(request.getStatus());
criteria.subCriteria(subCriteria);
var criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);

This approach returns the document with eventId: ID1 and the intention here is to return no value.
Is there a way to implement described behavior using the Criteria API? If not, which approach should be chosen otherwise?
